# Can I make the animation-timing-function affect the whole animation rather than each step of the animation?

Tags: css, css-animations

I have recently been playing a lot with CSS animations. The biggest issue I've had with CSS animations is the animation-timing-function. My issue with this is that the function is applied between each section of the keyframes. What I mean is that if I have a multi-step animation acting on a div:

```
@keyframes moveProjectTop{
    0%{
        transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) rotateZ(0deg);
    }
    50%{
        transform: translateX(125px) translateY(30px) rotateZ(30deg);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateX(250px) translateY(60px) rotateZ(0deg);
    }
}
```

What I want from this kind of transformation is for the translation motion to have a bouncing effect, but I want the rotation not to. I don't think this is possible with CSS.

I have been led to believe this because:

1: Transformations can't be split over two animations which means that all transformations have to be under 1 keyframes animation.

2: Animation-timing-functions apply between each step.

I think the solution would have to do with my second detail. Is there a way to have a timing-function apply over a whole animation rather than between each step (between two percentages). The other solution would be if there was a way to apply a different timing function between each step, as in if I could have ease-in apply between 0%-50% and ease-out apply between 50%-100%, then this would imitate an ease-in-out function.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I could smooth animations in one of these two ways?

Comment: Note even if the linked question is about the `-webkit` version of the property, it's the same issue. Correct answer being: **can't be done with CSS**. You need to either split the timing function correctly by doing the math yourself (which is close to impossible for complex cubic-bezier timing functions) or you could have a look at either Javascript libraries (i.e. [velocity.js](http://velocityjs.org/)) or [Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API) (which still has [support limitations](https://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea is to split the animation and instead of translation you can use `top`/`left` then you can easily control each one alone:

```css
.box {
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  background:red;
  position:relative;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite linear alternate,
              move 2s infinite ease-in  alternate;
}

@keyframes bounce{
    0%{
        transform:rotateZ(0deg);
    }
    50%{
        transform: rotateZ(30deg);
    }
    100%{
        transform:rotateZ(0deg);
    }
}
@keyframes move{
    0%{
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
    }
    50%{
        top:125px;
        left:30px;
    }
    100%{
        top:250px;
        left:60px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, splitting the animation is the only way I can think of making this work.

Comment: Given that it is supposedly not possible, I have labeled this as the best answer since it solves my issue.